# Sublime Text 3 FindNext in macro command

Tags: macros, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I am using ctrl+Q to record a macro. But it seems like it will not record the find next command.

I hit ctrl+Q, then hit find next hotkey, then right arrow key, then adding a string. Then I hit ctrl+q again.

When I run the macro it just enters the added string where even my caret is.

The reason I am doing this is because I am using a regex to search, and search and replace does not work with regex for replacing.

Comment: Sublime Text currently does not support dynamic functions in macros ( *pretty much anything that requires user input from a panel, and a few other things as well* ). I'm currently working on a solution for this & have [**verified it's functionality**](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/solved-issue-using-edit-objects-recursively/18400), but it might be a few months before release ( *I'm in the process of wrapping up a framework upon which to build it* ).

Comment: Thanks....and god speed. :)